# How do i extract value of an HTML table with Css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

For school I'm having to filter an HTML Table. The code has some CSS in it and iI have no idea why getting the `.value` isn't working - it always gives me `undefined`.

```js
function filtern() {
  var alles = document.querySelector('.list').value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = test;
  document.getElementById("ausgabe").innerHTML = alles;
}
```

```html
    <table class="mon_list">
      <tr class='list'>
        <th class="list" align="center"><b>Klasse(n)</b></th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Stunde</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">(Lehrer)</th>
        <th class="list" align="center"><b>Vertreter</b></th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Fach</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Raum</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Vertretungs-Text</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class='list odd'>
        <td class="list" align="center"><b>5a</b></td>
        <td class="list" align="center">5</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">Se</td>
        <td class="list" align="center"><b>Ma</b></td>
        <td class="list" align="center">BNT-b</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">2.25</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">Vertretung</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='list even'>
        <td class="list" align="center"><b>5a</b></td>
        <td class="list" align="center">6</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">Se</td>
        <td class="list" align="center"><b>---</b></td>
        <td class="list" align="center">---</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">---</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">frei</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='list odd'>
        <td class="list" align="center"><b>5c</b></td>
        <td class="list" align="center">1</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">Mü</td>
        <td class="list" align="center"><b>Au</b></td>
        <td class="list" align="center">M</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">1.23</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">Aufgaben</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='list even'>
        <td class="list" align="center"><b>5c</b></td>
        <td class="list" align="center">2</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">Mü</td>
        <td class="list" align="center"><b>Gi</b></td>
        <td class="list" align="center">M</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">1.23</td>
        <td class="list" align="center">Aufgaben</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </p>
  <p id="ausgabe"></p>
</center>
```

Comment: `td` elements don't have a `value` property. That's only valid on form controls. Assuming you want to get the text of the element, try `innerText` or `textContent`

Comment: Also the `.list` class is on a *lot* of elements. You most likely need a loop, or a more specific selector to pull out the text you want to target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a working example onclick event.As @Rory mentioned td elements don't have a value property. That's only valid on form controls. Assuming you want to get the text of the element, try innerText

```js
function myFunction() {
  var alles = document.querySelector('.list').innerText;
  var alles2 = document.querySelector('.list2').innerText;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = alles;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = alles2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table class="mon_list" onclick="myFunction()">
    <tr class='list'>
      <th align="center"><b>Klasse(n)</b></th>
      <th align="center">Stunde</th>
      <th align="center">(Lehrer)</th>
      <th align="center"><b>Vertreter</b></th>
      <th align="center">Fach</th>
      <th align="center">Raum</th>
      <th align="center">Vertretungs-Text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='list2 '>
      <td align="center"><b>5a</b></td>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td align="center">Se</td>
      <td align="center"><b>Ma</b></td>
      <td align="center">BNT-b</td>
      <td align="center">2.25</td>
      <td align="center">Vertretung</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo2"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i can't change the HTML document. But i got what i needed. When I'm finished i upload my Solution.